# meeting with Executive VP for Academic Affairs during faculty interview

Tags: interview

This is a first for me. This will be at a SLAC for a TT position. This is in addition to a dean so do you have any idea of what to expect from this meeting with the Executive VP for Academic Affair?

Comment: What's a "SLAC"?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth: "Selective Liberal Arts College".

Comment: I would guess this person's role is similar to that of a provost: the boss of all the faculty.

Answer (score 1):

At a small (selective or not) liberal arts college (or a small engineering college like mine), there will typically be relatively few faculty members and as a result, there may not be as many levels of management as at a larger university.

For example, at my institution, we have about 120 faculty.  Until recently there were no deans between the department chairs and the vice president for academic affairs.  Under that system, the vice president for academic affairs was doing the work that a dean might do within a larger university.  Note that he had fewer faculty than the dean of a large college within a big university might have to supervise.

The vice president will probably have questions for you that are similar to those that a dean might ask.

Comment: where I am interviewing these are two different people. Just not sure how different these two meetings will be.